# Android adb is not accessible and restarts itself in Android Studio

Tags: android, adb

I got this messages repeatedly in the `Android Studio Event Log` when using emulators(AVD)

```
4:08 PM * daemon started successfully

4:08 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

4:08 PM * daemon started successfully

4:08 PM Sending Tracking request failed!

4:08 PM Adb connection Error:Connection reset by peer

4:08 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
```

I run the app but it is not working and says:

```
Installation failed due to: 'device offline'
```

I tried:

```
$adb kill-server

cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused
```

I tried killing the process of adb and call `adb devices` but it is not working either.

The only working solution is to close my emulator and use physical device.

How to fix this?

```
OS: MacOs Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)
Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.5
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 3933M
Cores: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, my develop environment :

```
MacOS 10.15.6
Android Studio 4.0.1
Android SDK Platform-Tools 30.0.3
```

After some not-working attempts to fix it, I found that turning off wifi on my MacBook will stop the restarting of adb server.

Finally, I update the Android SDK Platform-Tools to 30.0.4 and it fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off my PC's wifi allowed adb to start..